# How to pass a large list of data from parent to child component

Tags: reactjs, redux

Say I have a parent component like this:

```
class ParentComponent{
    constructor(props){
        this.state = {
            children:[{...},{...}...]
        }
     render(){
         return(
             <ChildComponentList .../>
         )
     }
    }
}
```

And a child list like this:

```
class ChildComponentList{
    constructor(props){
        this.state = {
            ...
        }
     render(){
         return(
             ???.children.map(
                 <ChildComponent ... />
             )
         )
     }
    }
}
```

Now I obviously want to pass the children from the parent to the child list. I know you pass data from the parent to the child using props. But it doesn't make sense to me to say something like `<ChildComponentList children = {this.children} />` because children isn't a single value but a huge list. Also assume this is going to be a tree where the `ChildComponent` can contain more `ChildComponentList`s & so on.

Here's the options I can see:

- have some kind of `getChildren()` method in the parent and have the child list call it
- use Redux and put the children in the data store
- have each child component list retrieve its data from the database individually so I don't have to pass a big list down the tree
- just go ahead and put the whole list in the props even if it doesn't make sense to me

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why does passing it as props not make sense to you?

Comment: I second with @SakoBu. If you are already using redux, use redux, otherwise just introducing redux for this feels bit of an overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ParentComponent{

    constructor(props){

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items:[{...},{...}...]
        }
     }

     render(){
         return(
             <ChildComponentList items={this.state.items} />
         )
     }
}


class ChildComponentList{
     render(){
         return(
             this.props.items.map(
                 (item, i) => <ChildComponent key={i} ... />)
         )
     }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I guess there is no reason not to make it a prop. I was thinking of a prop as being something like an html attribute, because that's what ir looks like, but I see now it's much more than that.

Comment: Yes, @jimboweb. When you look the code, this "sounds like HTML", but don't forget, this is JSX, is an "XML representation" os Javascript Code, and not HTML :)